# Save Output Automatically to a new Json file every time the counter reaches a certain number Python

Tags: python, json, counter, large-data

I have several folders which each contain several CSV files which have a large number of rows and columns. I am trying to concatenate certain columns in the CSV files to a JSON file. My code works well when it goes through folders that have under 100 CSV files. If I try to files more than 100, the code becomes really slow, and it gets stuck after a few numbers of files.

I have created a mock data with 4 data frames that replicate my original data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

data_1 = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q'],

      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}

data_2 = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'],

      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}

data_3 = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['NaN', 'NaN', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US'],

      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}

data_4 = {'host_identity_verified':['t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
      'neighbourhood':['NaN', 'NaN', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US', 'Chicago, US'],

      'neighbourhood_cleansed':['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West',
                                'Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West', 'Centrum-West'],
     'neighbourhood_group_cleansed': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
      'latitude':[ 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719, 52.36575, 52.36509, 52.37297, 52.38761, 52.36719]}


df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data_3)
df_4 = pd.DataFrame(data_4)

df_list_1 = []
df_list_2 = []
df_list_3 = []
df_list_4 = []

df_list_1.append(df_1)
df_list_2.append(df_2)
df_list_3.append(df_3)
df_list_4.append(df_4)

df_all = df_list_1 + df_list_2 + df_list_3 +df_list_4
count = 0
li = []
for df in df_all:
    count = count +1
    print(count)
    if count < 3:
        df_n = df
        li.append(df_n)
        frame_1 = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index= True)

        def Get_Columns(file_name):
            return file_name[['host_identity_verified', 'latitude']]


        concat_data_1 = Get_Columns(frame_1)
        with open('Booking_Data_%s.json' % count,'w') as outfile:
            concat_data_j_1 = concat_data_1.to_json()
            outfile.write(concat_data_j_1)
```

As you can see, in order to get an x number of files to be concatenated and saved to a JASON file, I'll have to do this manually by writing many elif statements. I have a folder that has a little bit under 900 files thus I'll have to write around 19 conditions to save each 50 CSV files into a JSON file.

Thus I want to make code shorter and automatically save the output to a new JSON file every time the counter reaches a multiple of a 20. Save first 20 in a file, second 20 in a file and so on.

For example, I have 58 files in a folder. If I want to save every 20 files in a JSON file, I have to have 3 JSON files, the first 2 has 20 CSV, and the last has 18.

Also, will I face a problem analyzing my JSON files since they are too big? Is it the best type of file to save large data in? We are talking about close to million rows in each file if not more with hundreds of MBs in size.

Comment: Your code has undefined variables like `pd`. Provide some [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: also examples of how data look before and after concatenating something into json would be good as well

Comment: @Sugar I hope the edit helps.